# Why I can not inherit from multiple classes in swift just like it's library classes

Tags: swift

I try to create myPet by inherit from two classes but error for example:

```
import UIKit
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    // No Error
}
```

Then the following classes were defined then create new class myPets which I like to inherit both Dog and Substance. But error: Multiple inheritance from classes 'Dog' and 'Substance'

```
class Dog:Animal {
    func sound()->String {
        return "Hong Hong"
    }
}

class Substance {
    func livingCompound()->String {
        return "Consist of bio-molecule"
    }
}

class myPets:Dog, Substance {
    func itsAddress()->String {
        // Error:Multiple inheritance from classes 'Dog' and 'Substance'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Swift does not support multiple inheritance, following Objective C in this. This is NOT inheritance from two classes:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

It is inheritance from one class `UIViewController` and adopting the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. Read about protocols at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: "Adopting protocol! after inherited the class. Got it.

Comment: I would say that this syntax is kind of misleading. I Obj-C the protocols ware enclosed in "< >" but now it is in the same sequence which is not very readable. Hopefully some Apple Swift engineer will read this and add the syntax way to make the delegates more explicit - upvote if you agree. (Wishful thinking ;) )

Comment: Opinions differ :) I actually like the current Swift syntax much more than Objective C one, and I do not find it confusing. I always found Objective C syntax with < > not very natural to me.

Comment: Even if they end up not using `<>`, I still would like some way of distinguishing between protocols and classes

Comment: Agreed, hands down the most misleading (interface/protocol) syntax

Comment: Using <> litters the code all through through the project, better to use a single symbol for protocols, if the the <> come back I'm leaving, too much like xml.  Without any symbols refactoring is easy, just change protocol to class with no need to change <> everywhere but as a compromise one symbol would be great