# Swift: Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIViewController' and 'AVPlayer'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, inheritance, avplayer

I'm trying to add the `AVPlayer`class into my `view controller`so I can use the `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval`method so when the `AVAudioPlayer`hits a specific second while playing, I can call an action. When I try to inherit the `AVPlayer` class, I get an error: `Multiple inheritance from classes 'UIViewController' and 'AVPlayer'`

Could somebody help me get a work around this?

Comment: show the code please

Comment: I haven't added the method yet because I need to inherit the AVPlayer class (where that method comes from) which it won't let me and produces that line of error.

Comment: Can't you directly able to use that method using `.` like `AVPlayer.myMethod()` ?

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595506/why-i-can-not-inherit-from-multiple-classes-in-swift-just-like-its-library-clas

Comment: I see it now. Lets just say I want to stick with AVAudioPlayer, is there an alternative method that AVAudioPlayer uses "addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval"?

Comment: you can use protocols.

Comment: - addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock: is an instance method. Is there any reason why you're trying to inherit from AVPlayer instead of just calling the method on an AVPlayer instance inside of your UIViewController?

Comment: I've realized that I can call the method on the AVPlayer instance but the audio I'm using uses AVAudioPlayer and I would much rather still use it than AVPlayer because AVPlayer doesn't have methods such as playing(), stop(), numberOfLoops which I'm currently using for AVAudioPlayer. I'm now just looking for an alternative for "addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval" but in the AVAudioPlayer class.