# How to do multi-inheritance in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to implement a class (for convenience name it A) derived from `UITableViewController` and another(B) from `UICollectionViewController`. And there are a lot of things common, so I want to put them in class(C) and let A and B inherit C. Now A and B both have two class to inherit, but multiple inheritance is not allowed in swift, so how to implement this? I know there is no multi-inheritance allowed in swift, but I still want to know how to do the things I described above.

Comment: Have C inherit from UIViewController and the A and B inherit from C. Implement the table view and collection view protocols as required in A and B and just ignore UITableViewController and UICollectionViewController. They are basically just convenience classes anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I can not inherit from multiple classes in swift just like it's library classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595506/why-i-can-not-inherit-from-multiple-classes-in-swift-just-like-its-library-clas)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As stated in the comments by @Paulw11 is correct. Here is an example that involves **A** & **B** inheriting from **C**. Which I have named `DogViewController` and `CatViewController` (which inherits form `PetViewController`). You can see how a protocol might be useful. This is just an ultra basic example.

```
protocol Motion {
    func move()
}

extension Motion where Self: PetViewController {

    func move() {
        //Open mouth
    }

}

class PetViewController: UIViewController, Motion{
    var isLoud: Bool?

    func speak(){
        //Open Mouth
    }
}

class DogViewController:PetViewController {

    func bark() {

        self.speak()

        //Make Bark Sound
    }
}

class CatViewController: PetViewController {

    func meow() {

        self.speak()

        //Make Meow Sound


    }

}

//....

let cat = CatViewController()
cat.move()
cat.isLoud = false
cat.meow()
```

Answer (score 5):

Multiple inheritance is not allowed in Swift. You can conform any protocol instead. Protocols are like interfaces in Java.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have multiple inheritance in Swift, the way to go is to look at Protocols, but it is a rather big topic to be discussed in an answer.

There are also many other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595506/why-i-can-not-inherit-from-multiple-classes-in-swift-just-like-its-library-clas) with the same scope